# How to have UINavigationController use flip animation while push a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

Now I have four `UITableViewControllers`.

- A
- B1, B2
- C

I need the following effect：

- Select an item on A can push to B1
- Tap the rightBarButtonItem on B1 can flip horizontal to B2
- Tap the rightBarButtonItem on B2 can flip horizontal to B1
- Select an item on B1 or B2 can push to C
- Can pop to A at B1 or B2

All views (A, B1, B2 and C) should have NavigationBar.

Now I can navigate between A, B1, B2, C. I can also flip to B2 using the following code:

```
//self is B1
- (IBAction)b2ButtonPressed
{
    B2ViewController* B2 = [[B2ViewController alloc] init];
    B2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:B2 animated:YES];
}
```

But on B2 the NavigationBar is missing.

I have an app on my iPod touch has such feature. How can I make it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you show the view controllers by modal presenting, not by navigation controller's push or pop, you should wrap a navigation controller for the view controller in order to show the navigation bar:

```
- (IBAction)b2ButtonPressed
{
  B2ViewController* B2 = [[B2ViewController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *B2Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:B2];   
  B2Nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  [self presentModalViewController:B2Nav animated:YES];
  [B2 release];
  [B2Nav release];
}
```

And don't forget to setup left or right bar button item for navigation bar in your B2ViewController.

Comment: I need a back button on B2 so I can go back to A, I tried your code, I can only get NavigationBar with no button on it

Comment: Only -pushViewController: of UINavigationController can create a back button for you, if you present modal view controller, you need to setup the button yourself.

Comment: I tried to set `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`, but it does not show. Then I tried `leftBarButtonItem`, but it seems I cannot make it look like a back button, i.e. have the arrow on button's left. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't recommend to use a back button here since it's not pushed by navigation controller, but you can use an UIButton with a back-like image to simulate it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you make use of `UIView animations` to make the B1 view flip and when the animations is finished, add the B2 view on the parent view ?

I think, this would keep the nav bar as it is.

Comment: I have found a sample from Apple matching your description, I'm reading it.

Comment: Good luck. The idea is simple. Use UIView animations to flip B1 view and it also asks what to perform when the animation gets finished. You need to tell it that B2 view needs to get added when animation is finished (i guess also B1 view needs to get removed too. But if it is not, then in case of transition from B2 to B1, you can simply remove B2)